# Adding TextFields in a TableView To an Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've Created a textField to all the cells in the table view.

```
self.field = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 44, 222, 31)];
self.field.delegate = self;
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.field];
```

So All the rows got a textfield. But I want to Access them individually. One of my seniors asked me to add them to an array and use them and left me this one line code

```
[self.array addObject:self.field];
```

So what's next? how should I use them?

Comment: You could also subclass UITableViewCell and add a UITextField property to it, then you would not have problems knowing which textField belong to which cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField *fieldOne = [arrayName objectAtIndex:locationOfTheTextField];

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this is by knowing the indexpath of the textfields superview(ie the uitableview cell)..by knowing the indexpath.row u know which cells textfield u r using

first get the superview of the textfield in textfield delegate method like 
 -textfielddidendediting

```
UITableviewCell *cell=(UITableviewCell*)[textfield superview];
NSindexPath *indexpath=[self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
```

now u can use this indexpath to find to which cell the textfield belongs and save the value accordingly

Comment: @Chandu: If I understood you correct, I recommended this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead You can assign tag(Your indexpath.row) to yourTextField and You can get the data.Like

```
self.field.tag = indexPath.row;
```

For getting the Data from Field you can go with,

```
for (int indexVal=0;indexVal<noOfRows; indexVal++)
{
        NSString *inputData=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexVal].text;   
        //Add this to array or something and use it
}
```

Comment: what ever. i will work on the ideas you people told and i will get back with the result.thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating it in wrong way, you make a global object of textField then hows you know from which row's textField what text you are going to pick.

So you need to make textFields locally for each row and set tag to each textField accroding to indexPath.row.

```
UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 44, 222, 31)];
txt.delegate = self;
txt.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:txt];
```

Comment: I am having a picker view too. so for the selector method it has.,i declared it globally

Comment: self.field.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateSelected];.So if i dont declare it globally my pickerview wont work

Comment: No problem make table as global variable then access table's row and from that row find the textField.